# laptop boots to black screen after failed lubuntu installation

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, grub, lubuntu

I had a grub rescue error while turning on my system which happened due to failed windows installation over a lubuntu installed drive. Now to repair this I tried to re-install lubuntu but at the end of the installation it failed to install the grub boot loader. So, after I restarted I am now getting a blank screen without even being able to load the BIOS. CPU and fan runs but nothing comes on the screen. Ctrl + Alt + Del restarts to the same screen but none of the other key combinations does anything. Anything that can help?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hard disk from the laptop and boot to bios, then disable UEFI boot, turn the laptop off and reconnect your hard drive.